# Wrong directory location in css using npm

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-7

I added fontawesome to my site by doing these steps:

1. webpack.mix.js configuration.

   ```
   mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
      .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
   ```
2. `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
3. In my package.json.

   ```
   // Font Awesome
   "dependencies": {
       "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
   ```
4. In my app.scss

   ```
   // Fonts
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400,700&display=swap');
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&display=swap');

   // Variables
   @import 'variables';

   // Bootstrap
   @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

   //Fontawesome
   @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
   @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
   @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
   @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
   ```

When I run `npm run dev` the fontawesome css directory location in my `app.css`  is

```
url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?6b20949b3a679c30d09f64acd5d3317d);
```

instead of

```
url(../fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?6b20949b3a679c30d09f64acd5d3317d);
```

Any idea how to fix this? New to Laravel, migrating from Yii 1. Thank you.

Comment: Does the change in path giving you any error?

Comment: @Digvijay yes, if i don't add the `../` i get this error `downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.woff2?91a23e8bf2b4b84c39311cb5eb23aaa0`

Answer (score 0):

*try to use a relative path example:

```
@import '../fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
```